# Print array numerals on a single line in ruby console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

a = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7]

I want to print on ruby console 
1 2 3 5 7

I tried this

```
a.each{|i| puts i.join(" ")}
```

it throws this error

```
 undefined method `join' for 1: Fixnum
```

I tried converting each element to string and then print them

```
    m = a.map {|l| l.to_s}
```

then

```
    m.each{|i| puts i.join(" ")}
```

it still throws an error

```
   undefined method `join' for "1": String
```

How do I achieve the desired result

Comment: I might be wrong.. but I think you're applying join to each element, and not the entire array?

Comment: `a.join(" ")` - is this not required ?

Comment: `puts [1,2,3,5,7].join(' ')`

Comment: @dp7 yes. using the variable a is necessary here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the other answer isn't what you want, try this:

```
a.each_with_index { |n, i| print i == a.size - 1 ? "#{n}\n" : "#{n} " }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're close. Try this one:

```
2.3.1 :002 > puts [1,2,3,5,7].join(' ')
 1 2 3 5 7
```

Comment: the thing is I do not want to try it directly on the array but use methods on variable array 'a' to print the elements of the 'a' on the console.